# How to load the db result into object using c# with out using loops

Tags: c#

I am trying to store db result into object.

Can some suggest me how to store .

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(pluginManager.ConnectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT * from contacts ;";
    connection.Open();
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
    SQLiteDataReader dr;

    dr = command.ExecuteReader();
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);

    int rows = dt.Rows.Count;

    var contactData = new object[rows, 42];

    dr.Close();
    connection.Close();
}
```

I want to dump dr/ dt result into contactData with out using any loops

I have done through collection as below as well it is taking time .

```
List<contact> contacts = new List<contact>();

foreach (var contact in contacts)
{               
    contactData[counter, 0] = contact.first_name;
    contactData[counter, 1] = contact.last_name;
    contactData[counter, 2] = contact.email;
    contactData[counter, 3] = contact.alternate_email;
    contactData[counter, 4] = contact.title;
    contactData[counter, 5] = contact.department;
    contactData[counter, 6] = contact.contact_number;
    contactData[counter, 7] = contact.fax_number;
    contactData[counter, 8] = contact.website;
    contactData[counter, 9] = contact.company_name;
    contactData[counter, 10] = contact.revenue;
    contactData[counter, 11] = contact.team_size;
    contactData[counter, 12] = contact.bed_count;
}
```

So I don't want to do loop at all .

Comment: Could you suggest me if you know the solution to store the result in object

Comment: The alternative to a loop is Linq, but that would just be doing the looping for you.  And that's not going to work well with a 2D array.  You could do a jagged array pretty easily.

Comment: I know how to store data by using linq and loops but it is taking time if data is of like 15000 records. I just want to dump data directly with out looping through

Comment: Then I'd suggest not using a `DataTable` and instead loop through the results from the reader and put them directly into your desired collection, perferably a `List<T>` of a custom class that represents the data in the table.

Comment: I have  edited the code with list as well which I am using but also it taking time .

Comment: Pulling thousands of records from a DB will take time.  There's not silver bullet for that except limiting what you have to pull.

Comment: The loop isn't your bottleneck.

Comment: Why not use Cache to store your data in memory, so you don't need to care about the loop time?

Comment: I am storing this data into excel file and these rows will have status which will change randomly . So every time I need to get the latest records

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the way to do it. The alternative is to use ORM like EntityFramework, which will allow you to get ready objects from database.

ORM is Object-Relational Mapping - basically, the framework automatically converts columns from database. Instead of a loop, you write something like that:

```
using(var db = new MyContext())
{
   var contacts = db.Contact.ToArray(); // that takes all records
}
```

So, as you can see, no loop, ar least in your code. Beware that working with big data sets ALWAYS takes time.

Comment: Be good to elaborate on your answer with some more detail and a link.  Despite your suggestion being very good, the answer is not helpful as people will have to fully research EF

Answer (score 0):

Use Dapper.Net. It's a high performance micro ORM.

first: Create Contact Class that match database Record

```
   public class Contact
    {
        public string last_name {get;set;}
        public string email {get;set;}
        public string alternate_email {get;set;}
        public string title {get;set;}
        public string department {get;set;}
        // rest of properties .....

    }
```

Second: Call `Query<T>`:

```
    using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
     {
         List<Contact> contacts=  db.Query<Contact> ("Select * From contacts").ToList();
     }
```

**Update:**

Alternative solution: Using linq

```
     List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();  
    contactList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows  
            select new Contact()  
            {  
                last_name =dr["last_name"],  
                email = dr["email"].ToString(),  
                alternate_email = dr["alternate_email"].ToString(),  
               //... rest of properties
            }).ToList();
```